# Replace anchor tags with spans, and place the href attribute into the span

Tags: javascript, html

I'm required to perform a slight conversion on a string which contains html.

The conversion should transform `a` elements such that they become `span` elements. The conversion should also place the `href` attribute from the original `a` element into the span.

I have what I think is a working solution, but the code feels overcomplicated. I had hoped this may be possible with relatively little code, so I was wondering if anyone could suggest ways to make this code neater.

Browser compatibility is not an issue, as this will be transpiled by babel.

Here's what I have:

```js
const testHtml = `
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="http://www.google.co.uk">Google is here</a>
  <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="http://www.msn.co.uk">Msn is here</a>
  <h2>This is a heading</h2>
`

const splitByLinkEnds = html => {
  const split = html.split('</a>')
  const allButLast = split.slice(0, -1)
  const last = split.slice(-1)[0]

  return [
    ...allButLast.map(x => `${x}</a>`),
    last
  ]
}

const splitByLinks = html => {
  const split = html.split('<a');
  const [
    first,
    ...result
  ] = split

  const withReaddedOpeningTags = [
    first,
    ...result.map(x => `<a${x}`)
  ]

  return withReaddedOpeningTags
    .reduce((prev, curr) => [
      ...prev,
      curr.indexOf('<a') > -1 ?
        splitByLinkEnds(curr) : curr
    ], []).flat()
}

const transformLinkToTextOnly = linkHtml => {
  const linkHref = linkHtml
    .match('href="[^"]*"')[0]
    .replace('href="', '')
    .replace('"', '')

  const htmlWithSpan = linkHtml
    .replace('<a', '<span')
    .replace('</a>', '')

  return `${htmlWithSpan} (${linkHref})</span>`
}

const transformLinksToTextOnly = html =>
  splitByLinks(html)
    .map(x => x.indexOf('<a') > - 1 ?
      transformLinkToTextOnly(x) : x
    ).join('')

const result = transformLinksToTextOnly(testHtml)

document.body.innerHTML += testHtml
document.body.innerHTML += '<hr />'
document.body.innerHTML += result
```

---

**Edit**
I should note that the solution ought to work in node, ideally. I appreciate that the fact I include dom manipulation in the question is quite misleading, I included this more to attempt to create an easy working example that to demonstrate how the code might actually be used.

A further note, the performance of this code is not particularly important. It's only for relatively small amounts of html and gets run once when the application loads.

Comment: Thanks for this great question - I hope you get some good reviews, and I hope to see more of your contributions here in future!

Answer (score 4):

One thing to consider is the whole working with HTML as string. In the answer I'll assume you work within the web-browser. The web-browser can parse the HTML for you, this way you'll only have to work with nodes.

Here is an example:

```js
const testHtml = `
  <p>This is a test paragraph</p>
  <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="http://www.google.co.uk">Google is here</a>
  <a style="font-weight: bold;" href="http://www.msn.co.uk">Msn is here</a>
  <h2>This is a heading</h2>
`;

function transformLinksToTextOnly(htmlString) {
  const root     = document.createElement('root');
  root.innerHTML = htmlString;
  const anchors  = root.querySelectorAll('a');

  anchors.forEach(anchor => {
    const span = document.createElement('span');

    span.innerHTML = anchor.innerHTML;
    if (anchor.href) 
      span.innerHTML += ` (${anchor.href})`;

    anchor
      .getAttributeNames()
      .forEach(attrName => {
        const attrValue = anchor.getAttribute(attrName);
        span.setAttribute(attrName, attrValue);
      });

    anchor.parentNode.replaceChild(span, anchor);
  });

  return root.innerHTML;
}

const result = transformLinksToTextOnly(testHtml);

document.body.innerHTML += testHtml;
document.body.innerHTML += '<hr />';
document.body.innerHTML += result;
```

Comment: Thanks for this; I was actually thinking of using this in node, which I should have probably mentioned in the question, but it may be that I can take a similar approach using a library

Answer (score 0):

## Highly inefficient

The code is highly inefficient, wasting CPU cycles and memory due to poor use of Javascript API's. It is also badly formatted and thus hard to read and follow and poor naming also made working out what you were doing difficult.

### Code Points.

- Better naming alround. Example, you have two functions `transformLinkToTextOnly` and `transformLinksToTextOnly` Now I might be a bit blind but without spaces its not at all clear that these are two separate functions. If you consider the context of the functions and encapsulate them you can reduce the complex names to `transformLink` and `transformLinks` making the plural stand out, the rest is inferred due to context.
- Indent chained functions.
- Use semicolons to end lines. There are many arguments for and against using semicolons. Semicolons are required by the language, and are inserted automatically when javascript is parsed, however there are many edge cases that most people are unaware of and can catch you out. The rule of thumb is "Can you list all edge cases where semicolon insertion can cause problems?" if not use them. It is even more important that you are consistent. Even if you know all the rules, using semicolons in some places and not in others breaks the style rule "Be consistent".
- Avoid single use variable declarations.
- If you use terneries in multi expression lines, put them inside `(...)` for clarity. See example A
- Know your javascript. It is important that you are thoroughly familiar with the language you write in. You need to regularly review the JS reference and know the most concise and performant forms to achieve what you desire. Your code is very GC (garbage collection) unfriendly creating many arrays and thrashing memory and slowuing down the code, all of which can be avoided . See example B

### Example A

```
  return withReaddedOpeningTags
    .reduce((prev, curr) => [
        ...prev,
      curr.indexOf('<a') > -1 ?
            splitByLinkEnds(curr) : curr
    ], []).flat()
```

Better syntax written as

```
return withReaddedOpeningTags
    .reduce((prev, curr) =>
        [...prev, (curr.indexOf('<a') > -1 ? splitByLinkEnds(curr) : curr)]
        , [])
    .flat();
```

As I am at this function I will point out that for every iteration you make a new copy of the array, add it as another array, and in the end you are forced to flatten the result to get what you want.

The same can be done with.

```
return withReaddedOpeningTags
    .map(item =>  item.indexOf('<a') > -1 ? splitByLinkEnds(item) : item);
```

or

```
return withReaddedOpeningTags
    .map(item => item.includes('<a') ? splitByLinkEnds(item) : item);
```

### Example B

An example function `splitByLinkEnds` create 5 arrays

```
const splitByLinkEnds = html => {
    const split = html.split('</a>');       // array 1

    const allButLast = split.slice(0, -1);  // array 2
    const last = split.slice(-1)[0];        // creates array 3 an uses first item

    return [
        ...allButLast.map(x => `${x}</a>`),  // map creates an array 4 that is then 
                                             // copied to the return array 5
        last 
    ];
}
```

It can be done using only one new array.

```
const splitEnds = markup => {
    const parts = markup.split("</a>");
    const end = parts.pop();
    parts.forEach((x, i) => parts[i] = x + "</a>");
    parts.push(end);
    return parts;
}
```

or as

```
const splitEnds = markup => {
    return markup.split("</a>").forEach((x, i, a) => a[i] = x + (i < a.length - 1 ? "</a>" : ""));
}
```

### Rewrites

I have include 4 ways of achieving the same result. Javascript is very expressive so there is no single right way to do anything.

#### Rewrite using only strings and arrays

This method does not require the DOM and splits the markup at anchor boundaries creating an array of anchor descriptions which is then used to replace the anchors in the original markup.

```
function replaceAnchors(markup) {
    function findLinks(markup) {
        return markup.substring(markup.indexOf("<a") + 2).split("<a")
            .map(markup => ({
                markup : "<a" + markup.split("</a>")[0] + "</a>",
                anchor : markup.split(">")[0],
                href : markup.split("href=\"")[1].split("\"")[0],
                text : markup.split(">")[1].split("</a")[0],
            }));
    }        
    findLinks(markup).forEach(link => {
        markup = markup.replace(link.markup,`<span${link.anchor}>${link.text}(${link.href})</span>`);
    });
    return markup;
}
```

Second version does away with the intermediate array and does it in one pass.

```
function replaceAnchors(markup) {
    markup.substring(markup.indexOf("<a") + 2).split("<a")
        .forEach(a => {
            const href = a.split("href=\"")[1].split("\"")[0];
            const text = a.split(">")[1].split("</a")[0];

            markup = markup.replace(
                `<a${a.split("</a>")[0]}</a>`,
                `<span${a.split(">")[0]}>${text}(${href})</span>`
                );
        });
    return markup;
}
```

#### Rewrite with memory and performance in mind.

This uses named properties to determine what to do with each character in turn. If a `match[current]` is found then `actions[current].add` and `actions[current].action` are performed, each action sets up the next expected match and actions by setting the string `current` to the correct name. It is very fast and has a little room to go even faster. It is also very memory efficient

```
function replaceAnchors(markup) {
    const match = {
        get anchorStart() { return markup[idx] === "<" && markup[idx+1] === "a" },
        get hrefStart() { return markup.substring(idx,idx + 6) === "href=\"" },
        get hrefEnd() { return markup[idx] === "\"" },
        get tagClose() { return markup[idx]  === "<" && markup[idx+1]  === "/" && markup[idx+2]  === "a" },
    };
    const actions = {
        anchorStart: {
            add() { idx += 2; return "<span" },
            action() { current = "hrefStart" }
        },
        hrefStart: {
            add() { idx += 6; return "href=\""}, 
            action() { hrefStart = idx; current = "hrefEnd" }
        },
        hrefEnd: {
            add() { idx += 1; return "\""}, 
            action() { href = markup.substring(hrefStart, idx -1); current = "tagClose" }
        },
        tagClose: {
            add() { idx += 4; return "(" + href + ")</span>" },
            action() { current = "anchorStart" }
        },
    }
    var result = "", idx = 0, hrefStart, href, current = "anchorStart";
    while (idx < markup.length) {
        if (match[current]) {
            result += searchs[current].add();
            searchs[current].action();
        } else {
            result += markup[idx++]; 
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

#### Rewrite using the DOM

This method uses the Markup parser to help locate anchor tags and then just replaces the start and end tag with span and the additional href

```
function replaceAnchors(markup) {
    const nodes = document.createElement("span");
    nodes.innerHTML = markup;
    for (const a of nodes.querySelectorAll("a")) {
        const anchor = a.outerHTML;
        markup = markup.replace(anchor, anchor
            .replace("</a>",`(${a.getAttribute("href")})</span>`)
            .replace("<a","<span")
        );

    }
    return markup;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I completely agree about the indenting: I put the code together in jsfiddle and must have been using a mixture of tabs and spaces, sorry about that. It's corrected now. I like your point about wrapping the ternary statement in parentheses; I think that'd make things quite a bit more readable.

Comment: Some of the suggestions you make seem to go against the direction in which javascript is heading these days. Do you think that your style (`for` loops, `while` loops, manipulating state, avoiding single use variables etc.) is the better way of doing things? It's how I used to write javascript, but the trend of the language is very much against that these days.

Comment: I also agree with your comments on semicolons; I see some style recommendations against them, but it seems like they're a useful part of the language which both prevent bugs and improve readability.

Comment: @OliverRadini You asked  "Do you think that your style..."  "...is the better way of doing things?" The aim is to reduce the code size. The number of lines of code is by far the most reliable metric used to determine code quality. Each coder will have an error rate measured in bugs per lines of code, reduce the number of lines to do a task and you reduce the number of bugs. This is consistent across languages and paradigms.

Comment: That's interesting; it's new to me to have the reduction of the number of lines of code as a primary aim. It seems like, if you're looking for a quantifiable metric then it's quite useful, but this leads me to think that quantifiable metrics are unlikely to give a good indication of the quality of the code.

Comment: @OliverRadini You had 41 lines of code (excluding blank lines, setup, and testing) that (with blank lines) spanned over a page and thus needed interaction just to read, for a task that can be done in 12 lines. Now imagine a project with 1,000 tasks. Would you rather manage 41,000 lines of code or 12,000 lines of code? Concise compact code is always a sign of quality. Adding code just to satisfy readability is a sign that the coder is not comfortable with the language, task to complete, or lacking experience and not a sign of quality code IMHO.

Comment: I just don't think that you can use number of lines of code as a sole metric by which to judge the quality of code. I was originally wondering why the examples you gave go against the trends of modern javascript. Nowadays, the trend is towards avoiding loops, and avoiding mutating state. What is interesting to me is that in your examples you seem to suggest that it's better to mutate state and use loops. What I'd like to know more about is _why_ you suggest what you do, I'm just unsure as to what the number of lines of code has to do with it.

Comment: @OliverRadini By mutate state I assume you mean "No side effects" (sfx) as in functional programming. In single threaded Javascript it's impossible to  have no sfx, multi threaded (workers) gets closer but still to communicate requires using the context global state. I use lexical scope (encapsulation) to maintain state, you will notice that all variables and functions are encapsulated within the higher function, only relevant code can manipulate it. Javascript is built on lexical scope, to ignore it bloats code, slows execution chews power, and makes spaghetti out of simple tasks.

Comment: I see; so you think that the modern trend towards using functional patterns is problematic because this way of writing javascript is typically less performant than those which are happy to have side effects? I can see the validity to this point of view, though I also believe that code which aims to keep variables immutable, and avoid side effects, is typically far easier to debug and reason about. This may just be my experience of working with the two approaches, though.

Comment: @OliverRadini No not quite, functional programing is great, but not in javascript, it does not enforce immutability. It is trivial to forget a reference `const a = [{}]` and `foo(...a) { a[0].b = 1}` mutates `a`  There is no way to catch such a violation making the whole no side effects tenant collapse and untrustable. Languages must enforce the paradigm or it is just a waste of time. Asking coders to be careful  does nothing to fix the problem. It is impossible to write functional javascript because javascript can not enforce the segregation of state needed to make it trustable.

Comment: That makes sense; it's interesting that so much development is moving in a functional direction when the language doesn't support it. Perhaps this is why we're starting to see an increased interest in functional languages which can be compiled to javascript (ReasonML seems to be growing in popularity)